# Text length ValidationError in STRAPI with CKEditor

Tags: node.js, reactjs, strapi, ckeditor5

I am using STRAPI with custom rich text editor. I setup from this [docs](https://strapi.io/blog/how-to-change-the-wysiwyg-in-strapi)

Now If I write more than `234` word I gives `ValidationError`  in console.
I am trying to increase max text limit but I am not sure it is possible or not and from where we can increase word limit.

Here is I am using STRAPI version `v3.6.2`

```
{
    "name": "ValidationError",
    "value": {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "news1 edited",
        "description": "<p>asssadsdsdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdasssadsdsdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdasssadsdsdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdasssadsdsdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdasssadsdsdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdasssadsdsdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdasssadsdsdsdsdsddDDSDSFd</p>",
        "published_at": "2021-11-17T07:19:43.837Z",
        "created_by": {
            "registrationToken": null,
            "lastname": "user",
            "preferedLanguage": null,
            "blocked": null,
            "resetPasswordToken": null,
            "isActive": true,
            "username": "username",
            "id": 1,
            "firstname": "user",
            "email": "user@email.com"
        },
        "updated_by": {
            "registrationToken": null,
            "lastname": "user",
            "preferedLanguage": null,
            "blocked": null,
            "resetPasswordToken": null,
            "isActive": true,
            "username": "username",
            "id": 1,
            "firstname": "user",
            "email": "user@email.com"
        },
        "created_at": "2021-11-17T07:09:34.551Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-12-06T03:22:38.714Z"
    },
    "errors": [
        "components.Input.error.validation.maxLength"
    ],
    "inner": [
        {
            "name": "ValidationError",
            "value": "<p>asssadsdsdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdasssadsdsdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdasssadsdsdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdasssadsdsdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdasssadsdsdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdasssadsdsdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdasssadsdsdsdsdsddDDSDSFd</p>",
            "path": "description",
            "type": "max",
            "errors": [
                "components.Input.error.validation.maxLength"
            ],
            "inner": [],
            "message": "components.Input.error.validation.maxLength",
            "params": {
                "path": "description",
                "value": "<p>asssadsdsdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdasssadsdsdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdasssadsdsdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdasssadsdsdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdasssadsdsdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdasssadsdsdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdasssadsdsdsdsdsddDDSDSFd</p>",
                "originalValue": "<p>asssadsdsdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdasssadsdsdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdasssadsdsdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdasssadsdsdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdasssadsdsdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdasssadsdsdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdasssadsdsdsdsdsddDDSDSFd</p>",
                "max": 240
            }
        }
    ],
    "message": "components.Input.error.validation.maxLength"
}
```